# How to Connect Tableau to Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2

Tags: azure-data-lake, tableau-desktop

I am using the following link to guide me on connecting Tableau to ADLS Gen2 https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/examples_azure_data_lake_gen2.htm

I have got stuck at the first hurdle where the document states

> Start Tableau and under Connect, select Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2.
> For a complete list of data connections, select More under To a
> Server.

I don't have that option with the version of Tableau I just downloaded.

[image]

Should I be downloading a different version of Tableau to see the option to select Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using Tableau Public (limited connection options), but if you download Tableau Desktop (even on a 14day trial) it will work [image]